# Run python program via PHP page

Tags: php, python

I was trying to execute a basic python script (`print "hello world"`) via PHP .  I saw numerous such question of SO which helped me make a php script to run the program which looks like this:

```
<?php
$result = exec('python phptry.py');
echo $result;
?>
```

where `phptry.py` is the name of the hello world program. However the php page doesnt return anything (blank / white page) . Are any additional plug-ins required?

Also, my actual aim is to run a much larger python script which has a `list of tuples` ( which i unpack and print via python as of now) which i wanna display on the php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/shell_exec) instead as exec(). You could also try to use system()

Possible duplicate of: [Running a Python script on a PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808974/running-a-python-script-on-a-php-server?rq=1)

Comment: I dint find that one. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, hope that helps!

Comment: ok i did try using the shell_exec() but , i still dont get any result. Is it because i wrote the python script in pyhton 2.7.x , but i have multiple python versions in my computer

Comment: EUREKA!! `<?php echo shell_exec('phptry.py'); ?> ` works. Got rid of  `python ` before the python script name

Comment: Glad you got it working!